# Sql Reader retornando valor nulo

Tags: c#, sql, banco-de-dados, select, ado.net

Estou executando um `datareader`, porem não retorna nenhum valor, já conferi na tabela e as condições (`where`) do `select` existem na tabela.

O código segue abaixo:

```
public void consulta()
    {
        string sqltring = @"Data Source=tptspo01sql01.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=Tptecnologia;Integrated Security=False;User ID=******;Password=******;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False";
        string _sql = string.Empty;
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection(sqltring);

        string usu, pass, idemp1, idusu;
        usu = textBox1.Text;
        pass = textBox2.Text; 

        try
        {
            sqlcon.Open();

            _sql = "SELECT * FROM Login WHERE usuario = @usuario AND Passwd = @Passwd";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(_sql, sqlcon);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = usu;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Passwd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = pass;

            SqlDataReader reader2 = cmd.ExecuteReader();


            while (reader2.Read())
            {
                idemp1 = reader2["Id_empresa"].ToString();
                idusu = reader2["id_usu"].ToString();

                MessageBox.Show("id empresa " + usu + "\b" + "is usuario " + pass);
            }

        }

        catch(SqlException error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error + "Na segunda consulta de id empresa");
        }

        finally
        {
            sqlcon.Close();
        }



    }
```

Comment: Ficou difícil ajudar, pode ter me escapado algo, mas parece tudo ok, exceto que talvez os dados não sejam como você imagina. Por não ter certeza não votei como "não pode ser reproduzido", mas parece que não temos como ajudar, pelo menos não só com isso.

Comment: Jovem, mesmo que seu servidor não aceite conexão de qualquer IP não deixe suas credenciais assim abertas ao público.

Comment: nossa, verdade.. nem tinha me atentado, desculpe. e obrigado por ter editado. vou tentar ver algo estranho na minha tabela, volto qualquer coisa. obrigado

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda,
Resolvi, oque acontecia era: os dois dados que estava buscando na tabela, são do tipo INT, e eu estava querendo executar um datareader, que busca valores do tipo string. dai o erro, resolvi, aplicando uma consulta do tipo executescalar. Valeu